# Downloading Gridded CHIRPS data sets using python

Tags: python

I am working with Satellite Gridded dataset from CHIRPS, Here is the link to the dataset: https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/ working specifically with the African Daily dataset : https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/ , The data spans from 1981 to 2020, The Idea is to download the data using the url and be able to work with it, I have not worked with image or Satellite data before, and would appreciate it if I can get any help on how to approach this. thanks

Comment: Hi, Sillians, have you found a solution? I might have for you

Answer (score 3):

It would be better for you to work with CHIRPS netcdf dataset.

In this solution, I clipped the CHIRPS global dataset using the boundaries (xmin xmax ymin and ymax) of my study area ie Ghana.

```
#load modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
```

```
# load chirps global monthly precipitation data
!wget https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/global_monthly/netcdf/chirps-v2.0.monthly.nc
```

```
# load chirps precipitation data
chirps = xr.open_dataset('/content/chirps-v2.0.monthly.nc')
```

```
# select precipitation variable
pr = chirps['precip']

# select boundaries (xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax) and time period of interest
pr_ghana = pr.sel(longitude=slice(-3.3,1.2), latitude=slice(4.7,11.2),time=slice('1981','2020'))
```

```
# save clipped data
pr_ghana.to_netcdf('/content/chirps-v2.0.monthly_ghana.nc')
```

The nectcdf file should be easy to manipulate using xarray!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Paniel Adounkpe, Appreciate it. Will try it out.

Comment: Alright, hope it works

Comment: How can I use this to extract information using coordinates of a single point instead of area of coordinates?

Comment: Select variables like this for single point `pr.sel(longitude=1.2, latitude=11.2)`